# jQuery transition background color of selected element on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has semi-transparent black background .
I want to smoothly transition background color to more opaque. As the div (header containing banner image) is scrolled up.

I am using a plugin for parallax effect.
I tried this code from code pen to achieve the effect.

```
    var header = $('header');
var range = 200;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {

  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
      height = header.outerHeight(),
      offset = height / 2,
      calc = 1 - (scrollTop - offset + range) / range;

  header.css({ 'opacity': calc });

  if (calc > '1') {
    header.css({ 'opacity': 1 });
  } else if ( calc < '0' ) {
    header.css({ 'opacity': 0 });
  }

});
```

Comment: post your tried code please..

Comment: I have edited my question with the code iTried..

Comment: this code works for opacity but in need to change background color instead of opacity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your full code I can't give actionable advice but the way I'd go is to trigger a [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) event within your scroll grabber code. You could set one class with the initial background styling, and a second class to toggle between with the secondary styling.